designing power supply using LNK306DG
I am designing a converter circuit using LNK306DG and I have done this earlier. Now I have to swap the phase and neutral pins of the circuit, and what should be the changes I have to make in this circuit to work properly.

Are you going to use N as the DC ground for the rest of your system?

I want to connect phase to the ground and neutral will be connected ti the input of the converter.

What's the problem with just doing it? We don't have enough information here to suggest otherwise. What are the input and output connected to?

I was thinking that If I swap the phase and neutral, will that circuit work? Because I will be creating a zero voltage across the circuit effectively, so there will be no rectification effectively
